# How can I use cloud sql data in tensorflow? for a model of machine running

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-ml-engine

i need advice. Beginner on the Google platform. Is there any other way to use data from a database created in cloud sql as training data for cloud ml engine?

should I export the data as a CSV file and put it into the input of the tensorflow model?

or is there a way to access the cloud sql and import the data when training the model?

i would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice or a link. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exporting a CSV file. There are no CloudSQL TensorFlow readers.